# SQL Server 2008 - Best practice to call a stored procedure for each row of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to do the following:-

1. Perform business logic and select a list of Subscription Id's.
2. For each row of the above selection, call separate stored procedure to get list of agents subscribed for that particular subscription id.
3. Insert the result for each row in two other tables.

Now, I have used While loop for point 2 and used IF conditional statement to call different SPs for different Subscription ids.

Note:- The name of stored procedure to call in step two is dynamic and varies with respect to Subscription Ids. The structure which different SP's return is identical though. I have no control on these procedures and won't be able to convert these procs into TVFs and hence implementing Cross Apply (if it serves the purpose) will be an issue.

My question is that is there any way I can avoid this iterative approach and accomplish the same functionality by following a set based approach?

Comment: You can't really compose stored procedures into larger queries, and you've ruled out the usual recommendation (convert to TVF, leave a stored proc wrapper function that just calls the TVF so that other users are unaffected)

Comment: IMHO, the best I can do in this situation is create a wrapper function which actually calls the stored procedures based on Subscription IDs. So, my calling sequence would be My Stored Proc->TVF(Subscription Id)->Other Stored Procs(Subscription Id). Would really like to know if there is any better solution than doing the above.

Comment: TVFs can't call stored procs - only the other way around. Stored procs are pretty much the end of the line - they can use all of the other SQL Server objects, but most other SQL Server objects can't use stored procs.

Comment: Well yes, seems like changing the subscription Id based procedures to TVFS and calling them from my stored procedure might be the only solution. Lets see if anyone can provide further inputs on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I explained the best practices and the need to convert the stored procedures to TVFs in point 2, the client has agreed to it and hence the issue has been resolved now using TVFs and Cross Apply. Thanks.